# Best way to send data to the server from sencha touch 2.0 app?

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I am working on sencha touch 2.0 and i want to send a store instance, in which id's of selected items is stored, to the server but my problem is, i know that when call `getData()` method to the store it only gives me `model object`.Now i know that i dont send model object directly to the server.I am stuck here and really confused that which way i can send my store to the server that it receive the data object and successfully return the value.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want your whole Store data to server? If yes, then you have to iterate through the store data and create a JSON string which can be sent over to server.

Suppose this is your store:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('MyStore'),
allData = [];

store.each(function(record){
    allData.push(record.getData());
});

var dataToBeSentToServer = Ext.JSON.encode(allData);
```

Now send this "dataToBeSentToServer" to server as a parameter and decode the data in server side.

Comment: @Swar Is it advisable to add that as a method on the store itself?